# instagram rotating photo header not showing up

Tags: header, rotation, instagram, photos

my instagram page is missing the rotating photo header all of a sudden.  I cannot find anywhere where you show/hide it. There is nothing on the instagram help page about this, and trying to google this for some reason only shows twitter header results, nothing about instagram. Does anyone know how to make it show up again? I can see everyone else's instagram header fine. I had a few people check out my page and everyone agrees they don't see the header, so it's not just me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

the Instagram header shows after you have added 7 images or more. I think there is a certain time period when it activates after you have added 7 images or more.

Comment: I don't see what that answer has to do with the question about rotation.